# Excel 2010 64 bit odbc drivers

Tags: excel

I have a machine with Windows 7 64 bit and Excel 2010 64 bit.

Trying to create DSN in C:\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe. No oracle oledb connection found.

How can i create the above connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download, install and configure a 64-bit version. Start here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

Yes, it's a big pain for no gain.